# How to next highest point after the days lowest low in pinescript

Tags: charts, pine-script, stock, trading

I want to find the best low/high range.

```
//@version=4
study("Daily Open High Range")
plot(((high-low)/low)*100)
```

This works mostly fine except it will return results for the low against the high even if the high precedes the low, I want to filter these out.

Example of what I want to be filtered out
[image: example of what I want to be filtered out]

This would be great to be able to find, but I cannot begin to imagine how to code this.

The challenge here is that the high following the lowest low does not account for the best range in the day.

[image: best low high]

Example of a correct chart
[image: What works so far]

Answer (score 3):

Even I am struggling with with the same problem. I get error

Pinescript is refusing to accept value returned by barssince(somecondition)
as length parameter although there are few documents that seem to say that it is correct.

simply put

```
valueA = highest(high, 20) // point A
valueB = lowest (low , 20) // point B

valueC = lowest(low  , max(1, barssince(valueA == high)))
```

Even after ensuring that the length variable can never be zero, pine script keeps giving run-time error (pink exclamation bar) stating that parameter of lowest cannot be zero..